# Suppress the splash screen

Tags: debugging, emacs, splash-screen

I'd like to suppress the splash screen and set up

```
$ cat ~/.emacs

;Do not display the splash screen
(setqinhibit-startup-screen t)
```

However, it does not work as excepted.

When issue emacs, it still prompts

```
Welcome to GNU Emacs, a part of the GNU operating system.

Get help           C-h  (Hold down CTRL and press h)
Emacs manual       C-h r        Browse manuals     C-h i
Emacs tutorial     C-h t        Undo changes       C-x u
Buy manuals        C-h RET      Exit Emacs         C-x C-c
```

it report error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function setqinhibit-startup-screen)
  (setqinhibit-startup-screen t)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/gaowei/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at$
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/gaowei/.emacs" "/Users/gaowei/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x4009e8d9>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

How could I suppress it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There needs to be a space between `setq` and `inhibit-startup-screen`.

The error message is telling us that there is no such thing as `setqinhibit-startup-screen`; and, this is because the function is `setq` and the variable is `inhibit-startup-screen`.